# Powering up CentOS deployed OVF displays guest operating system not supported

Tags: vmware-esxi, centos6, vsphere-client

I've exported an OVF template from a working CentOS 6 VM. My cluster is on VMware ESXi 6.5.

To test if the export was ok, I decided to import back in by doing "Deploy OVF template..."

After successfully deploying the VM, I receive the following error when doing Power On:

> The guest operating system 'centos6_64Guest' is not supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is related to Compatibility.

Right click on the VM, and do:

1. `Compatibility`
2. `Upgrade VM compatibility`
3. Accept the warning with `Yes`
4. Chose `ESXi 6.5 and later`

The VM will now start.

Note: The instructions are for vSphere Client version 6.5.0.20000.